# How to get the new height from a .load() before showing the element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to change the height of `.right-content` prior to the element being shown with the `.show()` function. I want the new height to be equal to what the height would be from the loaded PHP page that was transformed throught `.html()`.

I haven't been able to find a way to get this height before the `.show()` function is called and thus when the page loads it sometimes is either cut off or way to large (as some pages are larger/smaller then others).

Is there a way to get the height and change it where the comment is located in this code? Thanks!!

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    jQuery.easing.def = "easeInOutBack";

    $(".right-content")
        .hide("slide")
        .load("homePage/start.php").html();
    $(".right-content")
        .show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 750);

    $('#footer')
        .fadeIn(2000);

    $(".button").click(function() {
        $(".right-content").hide("slide", {direction: "left"}, 700, function() {
            $(this).load("homePage/" + item + ".php", function() {
                // figure out how to get the new .load() height and set $(this).height() equal to it
                console.log($(this).height());
            });

            $(this).show("slide", {direction: "left"}, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: To get the height, it needs to be rendered on the page. You can stick it in some element that is off the page and read that value.

Answer (score 0):

The browser can't definitively know how tall the content will be, until it tries to render it. But the JQuery `hide()` function applies the CSS rule `display:none`, which means it won't be rendered, ergo the height is unknowable at that point.

Instead of `hide`, how about: `css("visibility","hidden")`. That will tell the browser to render the objects, but invisibly. You'll also have to replace the `show` method with a custom transition to change the visibility to `"visible"`.